# GWT : User Location

Tags: javascript, gwt, geolocation

In GWT, is there a way to find out the user's physical location (country, state etc)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A safer bet than HTML5's geolocation feature is [GeoLite City](http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecity) from MaxMind, a free (and slitghly less accurate) version of their GeoIP City product.
They offer [APIs for various languages](http://www.maxmind.com/app/api) - I'm sure you'll find one that fits your server side :)

Comment: Yeah, I was looking for this to suggest but I just couldn't remember the name. this is a really good thing.

Answer (score 6):

<s>You can use [HTML 5's geolocation](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html) feature in GWT using the [Geolocation API](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-mobile-webkit/downloads/list?q=label:API-Geolocation) provided by the [gwt-mobile-webkit](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-mobile-webkit/) project.</s>

edit: This feature is now included in the GWT SDK itself. See the [`geolocation`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.4/com/google/gwt/geolocation/client/Geolocation.html) package.

You'll only be able to use this on browsers that support this fairly new feature, though.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would use the HTML5 geolocation API. One of the procject's that you could use is the already mentioned gwt-mobile-webkit. If you need a solution that would be of a benefit to more users you could use a revers ip lookup. Use the following link to see one of the companies that provides reverse ip lookup.

http://www.ip2location.com/

Just to say one more - if you can afford to lose some of your users, or just cripple them, go for HTML5.